# angularjs + nested ng-form + $invalid css for main ng-form.$invalid

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I need to set a css class on the outer most ng-form, if for any of the children, grand-children ng-form, $invalid is true.

I have a plunker to check with this problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CDyBbZs3GAUrEfBrap8G?p=preview

has anyone tried this? any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is incorrect.

You need to add `border-style`:

```
.error{
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/d0Yijc8zkWOv4xfvcCcY?p=preview

The good news? Your understanding of Angular is correct! Angular supports what you want out of the box without any configuration.

> In Angular forms can be nested. This means that the outer form is valid when all of the child forms are valid as well.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Comment: hi, this solution works. how stupid of me! i think it's just Friday thing.

Answer (score 1):

The form element gets an ng-invalid class as well so this works in the CSS - you don't even need to implement your own `error` class:

```
form.ng-invalid {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The border will go away when all the inputs are filled.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qbnFK2kLE3Al74EdMbBH?p=preview

Comment: I have accepted "@Sam P"'s answer mainly for 2 reasons:
1. He is first to reply.
2. answer is to the point.

though your answer is also correct. Thanks!